# Python Page Rank Streaming Application using Hadoop, py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o27.partitions

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am trying to pass the page rank algorithm from simple python code to a Streaming application using python in spark which takes input according to a specific time (10) seconds in this case from another python script that place files into the directory, and this script was supposed to take them according to the time and analyze them , and when i run the following code i get error, which i do not know what cause the error, i tried to get .csv files,

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

def main(input_folder_location):
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)  # Streaming will execute in each 3 seconds
ssc.checkpoint(input_folder_location)  # 'mean directory name, Directory to be checked

links = spark.sparkContext.textFile(input_folder_location). \
    map(lambda line: line.split(',')). \
    map(lambda pages: (pages[0], pages[1])). \
    distinct(). \
    groupByKey(). \
    map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1])))

ranks = links.map(lambda element: (element[0], 1.0))
# iterations = int(sys.argv[3])
iterations = 4

    for x in range(iterations + 1):
    contribs = links.join(ranks).flatMap(lambda row: computeContribs(row[1][0], row[1][1]))
    print("\n")
    print("------- Iter: " + str(x) + " --------")
    ranks = contribs.reduceByKey(lambda v1, v2: v1 + v2).map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1] * 0.85 + 0.15))
    for rank in ranks.collect():
        print(rank)
    print("\n")

print("------- Final Results --------")
for rank in ranks.collect():
    print(rank)

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()

def computeContribs(neighbors, rank):
for neighbor in neighbors:
    yield (neighbor, rank / len(neighbors))

if __name__ == "__main__":
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    sys.stderr.write(
        "Error: Usage: StreamingApp.py <input-file-directory>")
    sys.exit()

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

main(sys.argv[1])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

def computeContribs(neighbors, rank):
    for neighbor in neighbors:
        yield (neighbor, rank / len(neighbors))
def main(input_folder_location):
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 3)   #Streaming will execute in each 3 seconds
lines = ssc.textFileStream(input_folder_location)  #'log/ mean directory name
print(" hello from app")
counts = lines.map(lambda line: line.split(",")) \
.map(lambda pages:(pages[0],pages[1])) \
.transform(lambda rdd: rdd.distinct()) \
.groupByKey() \
.map(lambda x: (x[0],list(x[1])))

  ranks = counts.map(lambda element:(element[0],1.0))
iterations = 5
for x in range(1):
    contribs = counts.join(ranks).flatMap(lambda row: computeContribs(row[1][0],row[1][1]))
    print("\n")
    print(" iter --------------",x)
    ranks = contribs.reduceByKey(lambda v1,v2:v1+v2)
    print("\n")
#counts.pprint()
ranks.pprint()

print(" finishing the task")
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()


if __name__ == "__main__":
     if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        sys.stderr.write(
        "Error: Usage: StreamingApp.py <input-file-directory>")
        sys.exit()

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

main(sys.argv[1])
```